# Using Ant with SVN

Tags: ant

where are the latest versions of these files?

I keep on getting the following error : **Reference svnant.classpath not found** with the following configuration:

```
<path id="path.svnant"> <pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnant.jar"/> 
</path> 

<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />
```

So I added these entries after blogging :

```
<path id="path.svnant">
<pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnant.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnkit.jar"/>
<pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnjavahl.jar"/>
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />
```

But I can't seem to find these files or the latest versions of them.

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can pick these up from CollabNet [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html).  A number of builds are available, select the one appropriate for your version of Subversion.  Each svnant-x.x.x.zip download linked to in that page contains the jar files you require.  You may also [need JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL).

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, why do you want to do Subversion commands in Ant?

Sometimes it's necessary. For example, if you use CruiseControl, you need to do the checkout for CruiseControl in your `build.xml` because CruiseControl doesn't do it.

However, most of the time, it's not a good idea. For example, you might use your `build.xml` to checkin the resulting built artifacts. This is not a good idea. You should be storing built artifacts in a release repositor where they can be available for other projects. Checking in large binary files into your Subversion repository will make your Subversion repository grow to tremendous size with little benefit. These built binaries take a lot of room and become obsolete in a matter of months.

We use Ant with [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy). Our builds are done with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org), and we use the `mvm deploy:deploy-flle` command in Jenkins to deploy our files into our Maven repository where Ant w/ Ivy can check them out for other projects. The stuff we deploy to other machines are kept in Jenkins.

[Martin Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12129844/368630) has answered you where you can find the files you need to get the Ant Subversion tasks working. However, my experience has been that it's simply easier just to use `<exec>` and execute Subversion commands directly. This way, you don't have to make sure that the Subversion API is installed and that it matches the Subversion client and server.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Our goal is to be able to checkout an application from our repository using a build file and ant located on the network. This way, new resources only have to launch an ant command that will checkout the code, and setup the Eclipse workspace to get them running quickly. Our application contains approx 40 projects and always a hassle to checkout and configure Eclipse. Our checkout would include Eclipse configs. We also use Ivy and Jenkins and very pleased with that.